# Fragmented data in Twisted dataRecivied

Tags: python, protocols, twisted

I am using protocol.Protocol to receive data from a server. As follows

```
from twisted.internet.protocol import Protocol, Factory

class MyProtocol(Protocol):
    def dataReceived(self, data):
        print data

class MyFactory(Factory):
    def startedConnecting(self, connector):
        print 'Started to connect.'

    def buildProtocol(self, addr):
        print 'Connected.'
        return MyProtocol()
```

When I receive large data, due to the TCP stream fragmentation, I only receive part of the incoming messages. I m trying to buffer the data I receive. However, I am not able to receive the remaining data. What is a good practice to receive all the data after fragmentation?

Answer (score 2):

This is a frequently asked question about Twisted.  [You can find the answer in the Twisted FAQ](http://twistedmatrix.com/trac/wiki/FrequentlyAskedQuestions#Whyisprotocol.dataReceivedcalledwithonlypartofthedataIcalledtransport.writewith).  Check out the classes that it recommends, such as [`Int16StringReceiver`](http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/12.1.0/api/twisted.protocols.basic.Int16StringReceiver.html) or [`NetstringReceiver`](http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/12.1.0/api/twisted.protocols.basic.NetstringReceiver.html).  Or, for a full-featured inter-process messaging system, check out [AMP (the Asynchronous Messaging Protocol)](http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/12.1.0/api/twisted.protocols.amp.html), which also has [implementations in other languages](http://amp-protocol.net).

Comment: I am using Int16StringReceiver. However, how can I override the dataReceived method to wait for all data?

Answer (score 1):

The function that you want to override is `stringReceived`.

When using `Int16StringReceiver`, `stringReceived` is entered after an entire length-prefixed string has been received, while `dataReceived` may be entered zero or more times during the reception of each string.

`dataReceived` is the call which the `Int16StringReceiver` uses to construct the complete packet before calling `stringReceived`. It might have to parse multiple strings received at the same time, or wait for a complete string to be received.

Comment: `s/one or more/zero or more`?  Several short strings could be "Nagled" together, resulting in just one call to `dataReceived` and many calls to `stringReceived`