# Detect the end of a raw data

Tags: python, qt, twisted

[Twisted](http://twistedmatrix.com/) has two data reception modes: a Line Mode and a Raw Mode, and we can switch between them using `setRawMode()` and `setLineMode()` functions.

the line mode detects and end of line and then calls the `lineReceived()` function.

From [Twisted doc](http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/8.2.0/api/twisted.protocols.basic.LineReceiver.html#rawDataReceived):

> def rawDataReceived(self, data):
>
> Override this for when raw data is received.

How can `Twisted` detect the end of a raw data and then call `rawDataReceived()` ?

**EDIT:**

I'll add this to to complete my question.

I'm using this Qt function to send data to the `Twisted` server

```
qint64 QIODevice::write(const QByteArray & byteArray)
```

I thought that using `write()` two times means that the Twisted server will trigger the `rawDataReceived()` functions two times too.

```
write( "raw1" );
write( "raw2" );
```

but data are received in one time.

Comment: How do you define "end of raw data"? Essentially, as @falsetru illustrates, `setRawMode()` switches your protocol back to "streaming" receive.

Comment: @oberstet I've made an edit to add more explanations about what I mean.

Comment: Yes. Because you are walking over TCP. And doing 2 smallish writes from app will most likely coalesce into a single TCP segment. Anyway: you cannot assume anything about in what chunks you receive stuff when using TCP. You might as well receive "ra" and then "w1raw2" or any other combination.

Comment: it means that I have to add some signature after "raw1" to separate them ?

Comment: Either that (at which point, you are again at "line mode" using whatever separator you chose) or (probably simpler, more effective), use a length prefixing scheme and http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/api/twisted.protocols.basic.Int32StringReceiver.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You asked:

> How can `Twisted` detect the end of a raw data and then call `rawDataReceived()` ?

In short, when you turn on `raw` your asking Twisted *not* to detect.

... but let me explain

When you talk about 'detecting the end of data' *inside* of a connection (I.E. if your not closing the connection at the end of data), your talking about an idea that is normally referred to as `framing`.

Framing is one of the primary issues you have to keep in mind when your doing application level networking programming, because **most** (networking) **protocols don't guarantee data framing to the application**.

Confusingly many networking protocols (of which TCP is one of the most notorious) will ***often but not always*** present data to the receiver in the same way as it is transmitted (I.E. As though it had framing, each `write` will cause one `read` to happen - but *only* in cases of slow-use and low-load). Because of this maybe-it-will-work-maybe-it-won't behavior the best practice is to always explicitly add/build-in some sort of framing.

The most common method to add application-level framing in TCP/Serial/Keyboard style interfaces is to use line-breaks as end-of-frame makers, which is what `LineMode` is about.

Turning on `raw` mode in Twisted is like saying 'I want to write my own framing', but I doubt thats really what your after.

Instead you probably want to look at some of the other helper [`protocol`s](http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/core/howto/servers.html#helper-protocol) ([netstring](https://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/api/twisted.protocols.basic.NetstringReceiver.html), [prefixed-message-length](https://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/api/twisted.protocols.basic.IntNStringReceiver.html)) that Twisted offers that will do binary framing for you (also see SO: [Fragmented data in Twisted dataRecivied](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11838836/3334178) by Twisted's author Glyph)

Answer (score 3):

Twisted does not detect the end of the raw data. It just calls `rawDataReceived` as it receive data.

Following is relevant part from Twisted code. (*protocols/basic.py*)

```
def dataReceived(self, data):
    """
    Protocol.dataReceived.
    Translates bytes into lines, and calls lineReceived (or
    rawDataReceived, depending on mode.)
    """
    if self._busyReceiving:
        self._buffer += data
        return

    try:
        self._busyReceiving = True
        self._buffer += data
        while self._buffer and not self.paused:
            if self.line_mode:
                ....
            else:
                data = self._buffer
                self._buffer = b''
                why = self.rawDataReceived(data) # <--------
                if why:
                    return why
    finally:
        self._busyReceiving = False
```

Comment: `rawDataReceived` is called when the first bytes are received ?

Comment: @GhilasBELHADJ, Not only when the first byte read, but every time twisted read data from socket.